# hreflang unique situation

Tags: canonical-url, hreflang, rel

i have a unique situation for my international site.
I have pricing visable on the EU,UK,CA,US stores and no pricing on the rest of world store. so my plan is to make the international store the main store with the rel canonical going there. but with the hreflang as follows... You all see any issue with that approch?

````
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
        <link rel="alternate" href=https://www.dummy.com/uk hreflang="en-GB" />
        <link rel="alternate" href=https://www.dummy.com/us hreflang="en-US" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/ca” hreflang="en-CA” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-BE” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-AT” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-BG” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-HR” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-CY” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-DK” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-ET” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-FI” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-FR” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-DE” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-GR” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-HU” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-IE” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-IT” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-LV” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-LT” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-LB” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-MT” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-NL” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-PL” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-PT” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-RO” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-SK” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-SI” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-ES” />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https:/www.dummy.com/eu” hreflang="en-SE” />```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this approach is that it's a lot of HTML code that is only for machines, not for users. The additional size will have an impact on the transfer size, load times and overall performance of the website which can have a negative impact on conversion rates. There can also be a significant impact on the execution time, especially if you have descriptive URLs that are build on each single request.

A better approach might be to just set the target language to `en` for the `eu` version:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/uk" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/us" hreflang="en-US" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/ca" hreflang="en-CA" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/eu" hreflang="en" />
```

Another approach would be to specify hreflang within XML sitemap files instead of within the HTML. By doing so you can keep your source code to a minimum and still have the intended, very specific targeting.